# Format loss xpages read only form

Tags: xpages, formatting

I am new to xpages. How do I retain formatting of an xpages form when it is read only?
Using 8.5.3.

Comment: Graham, what do you mean with "retaing formatting" when read only? What formatting do you lose? Please clarify and provide some example code if necessary.

Comment: Henrik, When the form is editable the boarders and shading for each field is visible. When the form is opened read-only, only the text is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Graham, when you open an XPage it's always in edit mode, never in read mode. If it messes up formatting, then don't save it. If you are familiar with XML jump to the source view to see what the issue is or use the outline control to navigate your way through the data structure.

Sometimes when standard html elements are used on an XPage by the developer, they won't render nicely in the UI, you will have to jump into source code to see what's happening.

Hope this helps, if not please provide more information about your issue and include screenshots so we know what you are referring to.

Comment: I think he is referring to seeing the XPage in the browser and not in Domino Designer, but we need Graham to clarify this.

Comment: Henrik, you are correct. The boarders etc. are lost in the browser when opened as read-only. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Henrik, I think I have sorted it out. I did not have a CSS applied.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your form design does not render based on the size of your input fields. you can do this by surrounding your fields with one or more divs or spans and set the css min-height to a fixed height.

Comment: Thomas, thanks for your suggestion. I think I have it sorted, I did not have a CSS applied.